# Is there a Huttese Sound Archive online?

Tags: star-wars, languages, online-resources

"Huttese" is the Star Wars Language spoken by Jabba the Hutt.  It was designed by sound designer Ben Burtt. I read on wikipedia that it was based on [Quechua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quechua_languages).

Now... I noticed that my 1 year old son speaks Huttese by default, I can even conversate with him in this language although I don't know one word.

So I was wondering... is there a Huttese voice archive somewhere so that I can learn his language and conversate with him?

I found some sites with texts on it but nowhere a site with e.g. mp3's to play.

Comment: Hey Edward ... reading your question it's a little akward phrasing and might make it hard to understand. Maybe take out the "somewhere"?

Comment: you ask, I perform! (im Dutch, my English is not that well)

Comment: No problems. Looks good now!

Comment: Sometimes these kind of sites have a hard time staying up because they are usually flatout copyright violations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an entire [Jabba the Hutt Soundboard](http://www.soundboard.com/sb/Jabba_the_Hut_Sound.aspx).  This doesn't seem like enough to be everything from all the movies Jabba appeared in, so I think these are all from Episode VI.

Comment: wow! this one is very cool. tanx

Answer (score 2):

These sites have extensive Huttese translations, but no sound files that I could find.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Huttese

http://huttese.freeweb.hu/

Answer (score 0):

There's also a lot of spoken Huttese that actually makes sense in the Star Wars: The Old Republic MMORPG (free to play) if you visit Nar Shadaa (in the form of Blade Runner-esque voice ads heard throughout the city). [I tried translating these long ago](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=313103):

Magoosa mogootu chone kee
(Myself better and under) 
I'm better and cheaper?

Chess ko leeska con dumpa
(Take care/beware cheating poor garbage)
Beware of low quality counterfitting?

Wamma oto che copah u ta pawa
(to pay I want price you the power)
I want you to pay a good price for the power?

Ya tuta bu pa foo creeda,
(There from the place with credit)

Foto mo creeda chay-chay
(double or credit about)

choppa inka bunga an chawa
(pods amazing and race)
Amazing Pod Races?

Nagu kee shi hataw wompa
(? ? upgrade one)

Mojee-rah wantahompa
payment guaranteed

Doe ko wamma wanga
(The ? pay once)

Ooma coo pa whirlee
Head who place dancers
The top club with dancers?